# Replace all elements of a Seq from a String

Tags: scala

I have a `String` and a `Seq` like :

```
Array[String] = Array(a, the, an)

String = "This is a sentence that includes articles a, an and the"
```

I want to replace each element of the `Seq` within the String with `""`

Currently, I'm doing something like :

```
val a = Array("a" , "the", "an" )
var str = "This is a sentence that includes articles a, an and the"
a.foldLeft( "" ){ (x,y) => str=str.replaceAll(s"\\b${x}\\b", ""); str }
```

It seems to be working but doesn't look very *Scala-ish* mostly because of the re-assignment of the string for each iteration.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just

```
a.foldLeft(str) { (x,y) => x.replaceAll(s"\\b${y}\\b", "") }
```

For `foldLeft`, `x` is already the intermediate result you want, no need to store it in a `var`.

(As a side note, your original code doesn't work correctly in general: if `a` is empty, it'll return `""` instead of `str`.)

Comment: I'm getting `an` as the ouput when I run your statement.

Comment: And I'm getting the original String if I run the original code with an empty Array.

Comment: Sorry, flipped `x` and `y`.

Comment: "And I'm getting the original String if I run the original code with an empty Array." With empty array, you'll get back the first argument of `foldLeft`, the function never gets called. Are you sure you have `a.foldLeft( "" )` and not `a.foldLeft( str )` in the original code?

Comment: My bad, My Array was `Array( "" )` not `Array[String]()`. You are right, it won't work with an empty array. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the correct variant:

```
a.foldLeft(str){ case (acc,item) => acc.replaceAll(s"\\b${item}\\b", "")}
```